# File .htaccess is not working in php osclass cms

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system, osclass

error in osclass cms

File .htaccess couldn't be filled out with the right content. Here's the content you have to add to the .htaccess file. If you can't create the file, please deactivate the Friendly URLs option.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /clickgetview/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /clickgetview/index.php [L]
</IfModule
```

Answer (score 1):

File .htaccess couldn't be filled out with the right content. Here's the content you have to add to the .htaccess file. If you can't create the file, please deactivate the Friendly URLs option.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /clickgetview/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /clickgetview/index.php [L]
</IfModule
```

Comment: This is my problem also...Plz answers friends!

Comment: You need to create (if it doesn't exists yet) a file called .htacces in the root folder of your Osclass installation with that content